# SUPEE 7405 Image permission issue

Tags: supee-7405

Having issues with image permissions after installing SUPEE 7405– when uploading images, they are being defaulted to 640 permissions – any thoughts?

Comment: I also have same issue in EE1.13.x. I have reported it to magento team.

Comment: no need to report it, because magento probably already paid for this fix and thats why we have this patch...